# Callback URL in Skydrive API for Javascript

Tags: javascript, api, onedrive

I am using Javascript to connect to Skydrive API. My first step was to give an oAuth permission to initiator. What i did was set call back uri to my own website. whenever i get connect to service it  opens my callback uri (after taking scopes & permissions). and then i have my call back uri as

```
mydomain.com#accessToken=dsfe23423v{710 chars}
```

The thing is i am using pure client side JS/HTML/HTML%.. there was no way i am able to capture this access token and i have to manually hardcode it to use it further... Could you see what can be issue:

Here is my code::

```
<script src="http://js.live.net/v5.0/wl.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var APPLICATION_CLIENT_ID = '0000X00004003C03',
            REDIRECT_URL = "http://www.myweb.com";

    WL.Event.subscribe("auth.login", onLogin);
    WL.init({
        client_id: APPLICATION_CLIENT_ID,
        redirect_uri: REDIRECT_URL,
        scope: 'wl.skydrive_update',
        response_type: "token"
    });
    WL.ui({
        name: "signin",
        element: "signInButton",
        brand: "hotmail",
        type: "connect"
    });
    function greetUser(session) {
        var strGreeting = "";
        WL.api(
                {
                    path: "me",
                    method: "GET"
                },
                function (response) {
                    if (!response.error) {
                        strGreeting = "Hi, " + response.first_name + "!"
                        document.getElementById("greeting").innerHTML = strGreeting;
                    }
                });
    }

    function onLogin() {
        var session = WL.getSession();
        if (session) {
            greetUser(session);
        }
    }

    var apiURL = "https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me/";
    var tokenAuth = "E ----- 3d";

    //token is hardcoded above and then further utilized....

    var tokenAuthParam = "?access_token=" + tokenAuth;

</script>

<body>
<div id="greeting"></div>
<div id="signInButton"></div>

</body>
```

The problem is i have to hardcode access token which is not right. i should have somehow be able to get the access token from the callback uri.. i just wanted to know how can i get that. ( i am using complete client side coding)

Comment: i thought i was clear.. added few lines @ bottom again.. sorry for the confusion

Comment: Can you explain where you stuck on getting token from JS script? Sorry if it in your code already, I can't see it.

Answer (score 1):

To get the current access token, you can use

```
WL.getSession().access_token
```